# Decomposing the restrictions to $S_3$ of representations of $S_4$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be the standard reputation of $S_4$ and $W$ the unique 2-dimensional representation. I am told that restricting to $S_3$ we should have

$\text{Res}_{S_3}V = V'\oplus 1,\quad\text{Res}_{S_3}(V\otimes\text{sgn})=V'\oplus\text{sgn},\quad\text{Res}_{S_3}W=V'$

where $V'$ is the standard representation on $S_3$. But how do I compute this?

Comment: I would probably use characters to see this (assuming you know that a complex character specifies a representation up to isomorphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, looking at characters is probably the simplest way to go about it. However here is an alternative more combinatorial approach:

If we think of $V$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{C}^4$ where the sum of the coordinates is zero, the decomposition $Res_{S_3}V = V' \oplus 1$ is just given by the subspace where the last coordinate is zero plus the subspace spanned by $(1,1,1,-3)$.

The tensor products commute with restriction. In particular this is equal to $Res(V) \otimes Res(\text{sgn})$ which is just $(V' \oplus 1) \otimes \text{sgn}$ by the first result. One then needs to check that $V' \otimes \text{sgn}$ is $V'$, but $V'$ is the unique irreducible of dimension $2$ so this must be true.

$S_4$ acts on the set of set-partitions of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into two sets of size 2. There are three such partitions $\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}, \{\{1,3\},\{2,4\}\}$, and $\{\{1,4\},\{2,3\}\}$. Restricting to $S_3$ this action is equivalent to the standard action on $\{1,2,3\}$, which can be seen by just looking at what gets paired with $4$. $W$ is just the space of formal linear combinations of these partitions where the sum of the coefficients is zero, hence $Res(W) = V'$.